# Vue Mixin not recognized in PhpStorm

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, phpstorm, inertiajs

I have an app build with Laravel, Inertia and Vue3 but PhpStorm is not recognizing the imported mixin. The file is loading and functionality is working but PhpStorm keeps telling me I am calling an unrecognized function.

My app.js file:

```js
import './bootstrap';

import {createApp, h} from 'vue';
import {createInertiaApp} from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';
import {resolvePageComponent} from 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers';

import dayjs from 'dayjs'
import store from './store/index.js';
import MainMixin from './mixins/mainMixin.js';
import ValidationMixin from './mixins/validationMixin.js';
import vClickOutside from "click-outside-vue3"

createInertiaApp({
    resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')),
    setup({el, App, props, plugin}) {
        const VueApp = createApp({render: () => h(App, props)});

        VueApp.config.globalProperties.dayjs = dayjs;

        VueApp.use(plugin)
            .use(store)
            .use(vClickOutside)
            .mixin(MainMixin)
            .mixin(ValidationMixin)
            .mount(el)
    },
});
```

And when calling a function from this validation mixin it is not recognized:

[image]

Comment: Please share a complete code sample/example app the issue can be reproduced with (within a [support ticket](https://jbs.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/requests/new?ticket_form_id=66731) or [youtrack ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB))

Comment: This is full Laravel installation with Inertia and Vue. I can only give access to my private repository if you like? Don;t know how to share code without the rest of the application

Comment: access to a repo would be helpful; but I'd suggest creating a support ticket first to keep everything private

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the issue. Vue3 is not working with mixins anymore but they have to be converted to composables. (But mixins are still workling.)
Thnx Lena for your support!